# Can't find property or field on a dynamic object

Tags: c#, linq

I using [Dynamic Linq](https://github.com/kahanu/System.Linq.Dynamic) to do some database queries and it's working really well up to now. I can pass a string to a `Select` to select fields like so:

```
var output = myDatabaseTable.Select("Foo, Bar");
```

For example. The power obviously being when you pass a string variable rather than hardcoded strings. The problem I'm running into now is that the library using `IEnumerable` instead of `IEnumerable<T>` because, obviously, it can't know `T` until runtime. I'm using this to select data and eventually return it to a client and it works fine for spitting out raw data, but now I want to be able to do some more processing before returning the data and that requires getting the query to run on the database first. I can do something like this:

```
var materializedResults = output.Cast<dynamic>().ToList();
```

And that will make the query run. But the problem is, once I've done that, it seems I can't use dynamic linq anymore. For example, if I did something like this:

```
var foos = materializedResults.Select("Foo");
```

I now get a `System.Linq.Dynamic.ParseException` with the message `No property of field 'Foo' exists in type 'Object'` (Note: I can see in the debugger that the `materializedResults` does actually have all the expected properties).

So after casting to a `List` so I can potentially iterate through it and modify some of the values, I can no longer query it.

So my question is, how can I take a dynamic query (with select, group by, order by etc provided as strings), materialize the results and then actually process those result dynamically?

I thought maybe if I could cast to the actual type rather than `dynamic` it might work, so I tried this:

```
var d = output.Cast<dynamic>().ToList();
MethodInfo method = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethod("Cast", new[] {typeof(IEnumerable)});
method = method.MakeGenericMethod(d.First().GetType());
output = method.Invoke(d, new[] {d}) as IEnumerable;
```

Which is ugly and requires me to cast twice. The first time to `dynamic` so I can get the type from the first item then again to that type.

Comment: This is a bit tangential to your question, but what exactly are you achieving here that isn't achieved just as well with a plain old `DataTable`? The whole benefit of LINQ (strongly typed translations from C# to some query provider) is completely eliminated this way, doubly so if you have to throw in reflection like this.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: A fair point, but I'm quite a way into it now. I think it is marginally (and these challenges not withstanding) easier that constructing complex SQL statements by hand. I'm joining several tables / views / table value functions / stored procs into a mash up of data. Aside from that, I now want to make it work on principle!

Comment: @JeroenMostert: I'll also add, you still get some of the LINQ benefits, like deferred execution (that I now need to undo!)

Comment: I was afraid it was going to be something like that. :-) Carry on -- I'll stick with the hand-written complex SQL (and LINQ to Objects, which is still great).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do `YourStuff.Cast<dynamic>.ToList()`, you will receive `IEnumerable<object>`, and there is no property `Foo` on the type `object`.

The question you might be asking, how can you get `IList<TheActualType>`?! You can do it this way:

```
// for IEnumerable
public static IList ToAnonymousList(this IEnumerable enumerable)
{
    var enumerator = enumerable.GetEnumerator();
    if (!enumerator.MoveNext())
        throw new Exception("?? No elements??");

    var value = enumerator.Current;
    var returnList = (IList) typeof (List<>)
        .MakeGenericType(value.GetType())
        .GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes)
        .Invoke(null);

    returnList.Add(value);

    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        returnList.Add(enumerator.Current);

    return returnList;
}

    // for IQueryable
    public static IList ToAnonymousList(this IQueryable source)
    {
        if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");

        var returnList = (IList) typeof (List<>)
            .MakeGenericType(source.ElementType)
            .GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes)
            .Invoke(null);

        foreach (var elem in source)
            returnList.Add(elem);

        return returnList;
    }
```

It's a simple extension method that can later be used, as such:

```
var test = (new[]
{
    new
    {
        Property1 = "10",
        Property2 = "10",
        Property3 = 1
    }
}
.Select("New(Property1, Property2)"))
.ToAnonymousList();
```

Comment: Thanks. That's much, much cleaner than the solution I had.

Answer (score 0):

Your Cast is Defaulting to which will cause an error

```
(output as System.Collections.Generics.IEnumerable)
```

This Cast Specified the Correct Interface Try again

```
(output as System.Collections.IEnumerable).Cast<dynamic>().ToList()
```

Comment: You just posted the same answer and then deleted it. I appreciate your enthusiasm, but it's still wrong. I have already casted to `IEnumerable` and I have no problems with `Cast<dynamic>`. It doesn't give me errors, it just doesn't give me what I need.