# Dynamic Linq on Dapper dynamic collections - possible?

Tags: c#, linq, dapper

We are investigating using LinQ to query an internal dynamic collection created by Dapper. The question is:

How to execute dynamic LinQ against the collection using Scott Guthrie dynamic linq (or some other technology if possible)? (http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library)

This is what we want to do (much simplified):

Use Dapper to return a dynamic collection (here called rows):

```
rows = conn.Query(“select ACCOUNT, UNIT, AMOUNT from myTable”);
```

If we use a “static” LinQ query there is no problem. So this works fine:

```
var result = rows.Where(w => w.AMOUNT > 0);
```

But we would like to write something similar to this using dynamic Linq:

```
var result = rows.Where("AMOUNT > 0");
```

But we can’t get this to work.

The error we get is:

> No property or field ‘AMOUNT’ exists in type ‘Object’

(We have tried a lot of other syntax also – but cant get it to work)

Please note: We **do not** want to use dynamic SQL when Dapper requests data from the database (that is easy). We want to execute many small dynamic Linq statements on the collection that the Dapper query returns.

Can it be that ScottGu dynamic Linq only works with ‘LinQ to SQL’?

Is there some other alternative approach to achieve the same thing?
(Performance is a key issue)

/Erik

Answer (score 2):

```
conn.Query("...")
```

returns an `IEnumerable<dynamic>`. However, "dynamic LINQ" pre-dates `dynamic`, and presumably nobody has updated it to work with `dynamic`; it could certainly be done, but it is work (and isn't trivial). Options:

- use `Query<T>` for some `T`
- make the required changes to "dynamic LINQ", and preferably make those changes available to the wider community

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that `conn.Query(“select ACCOUNT, UNIT, AMOUNT from myTable”);` returns `IEnumerable<object>`.  In order for DLinq to work, you need to have `IEnumerable<TheActualType>`.

You can try this:

```
conn.Query<dynamic>("yourQueryString")
   .ToList()
 //.ToAnonymousList()
   .Where("AMOUNT > 0");
```

If that doesn't work, you could try and use [ToAnonymousList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26493018/cant-find-property-or-field-on-a-dynamic-object/26496399#26496399), that tries to return the `IList<TheActualType`.

Comment: But we do not want to push the "AMOUNT > 0" down to SQL-server. We want to execute it on the result collection "in memory"

Comment: The second problem is that we have no "ActualType". This is a reporting solution that will query a lot of different data sources. Sometime the result will be 5 columns, sometimes 20. And with different numbers of dimensions and measures. So we must work with the 'dynamic collection', i.e. we can not cast it into some fixed structure. (thanx for your reply, appreciated)

Comment: @user2512533, yes I understand. Either use ToList() or ToAnonymousList() that I've given, see if they work.